# When and where did "perk" become the common shortened form of "perquisite"?

Tags: etymology

[Merriam-Webster cites](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perk) 1824 as the first usage of "perk" as a noun as short for "perquisite". I'm curious if this occurred in a particular location (e.g., America or England) or if we know any more about the circumstances when the short form gained popularity.

Comment: There's extra info on this page, on M&W https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perquisite

Answer (score 11):

### It comes from Scotland

The 1824 date comes from the earliest date for *[pirkas/pirkus](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd00078706)* given in the Dictionary of the Scots Language:

> An unofficial emolument or addition to one's income, a gratuity, tip, perquisite, “perk” (Gall. 1824 MacTaggart Gallov. Encycl. 383, pirkus).

That reference is for [The Scottish Gallovidian encyclopedia](https://archive.org/stream/scottishgallovi00mactgoog/scottishgallovi00mactgoog_djvu.txt), which contains an entry for "pirkus" (but not *perks*).

In later dictionaries such as The [English Dialect Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=oUQ2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA520&dq=%22PIRKAS%22%20scots&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8_bzdm4T9AhX7MlkFHVI_BW8QuwV6BAgGEAY#v=onepage&q=Perk&f=false) (1903), "perks" is labeled as "Sc. Lon. Slang."

Comment: If I understand the *OED* correctly, it did not come from Scotland. Rather Scottish shortened *perquisite* to *pirkuz* before English shortened *perquisite* to *perk*. Not *perquisite* > *pirkuz* > *perk*.

Answer (score 6):

> ***Perk*** was formed by shortening and altering ***perquisite***.([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perquisite))

About ***perk***, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=perk&utm_source=extension_submit) also says that indeed it is a shortened version of ***perquisite***:

> ***1869***, a shortened, *colloquial* form of perquisite (q.v.), also ***perq***. As a verb, 1934 as a shortened and altered form of percolate, also perc.

So the year this usage appeared seems to be 1869.

I have not found the example from 1824 you mention.

[EclecticLight](https://eclecticlight.co/2015/03/24/in-a-word-perk/) explains

> In the nineteenth century (first recorded in ***1869***), the old word ***perquisite*** *increasingly became abbreviated to **perk**,* in the sense of a non-monetary benefit associated with a job or work. Thus someone working in a factory might take home an empty wooden palette on the basis that it is *a perk of the job*.

Ngram finds examples as early as *1873*:

> - On the other hand , the personal friends of Bummer, that is to say, the men whom he had put into "soft places," or who had shared his ***"perks,"*** - supported him for many cogent reasons. (*[The Atlantic Monthly](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zF8CAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22his%20perks%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdluKhnoT9AhXEoVwKHc4pDwcQ6AF6BAgGEAI) - Volume 32*, 1873)
> - Besides , you can have no idea what an amount per year you put into cook's purse through the medium of her ***“perks.”*** (*[Economical housewife](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AfAHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22her%20perks%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA6bOfnYT9AhVbiP0HHdOVBTUQ6AF6BAgCEAI)*, 1880)

Comment: Also, from James Greenwood, [_The Seven Curses of London_](https://books.google.com/books?id=NG_RTfBwA04C&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Seven+Curses+of+London%22+%22James+Greenwood%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik-JLB1YT9AhXipFsKHXmqCBcQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22perks%22&f=false) (1869): "Ordinarily it [petty pilfering] is called by the cant name of 'perks,' which is a convenient abbreviation of the  word "perquisites," and in the hands of the users of it, it shows itself a word of amazing flexibility."

Comment: I was looking for that one, but I gave up too early :)

Comment: Greenwood may be responsible for the three earliest instances of _perks_ (for perquisites) in published English: the 1869 instance I noted above; the 1874 instance cited by Green (and noted in user 66974's answer), and an instance from "[Studies of Street-Life in London](https://books.google.com/books?id=sss1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA601&dq=perquisite+perk&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje5Pfs14T9AhU0CTQIHW2iDjo4vgEQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=perquisite%20perk&f=false)," in the May 1871 issue of _The Eclectic Magazine_. In each case, Greenwood defines the term for readers who may not know it.

Answer (score 5):

Actually [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/perk) suggests a later date (1869) for perk as well as [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/2lxs3gy) whose early  usage examples are from BrE, AusE and AmE. Apparently the short form of perquisite became popular in main English  dialects quite quickly:

***perk*** n.1
also perq
[SE perquisite]
a bonus, esp. that which comes with a job; usu. in pl.

> 1874  [UK]    J. Greenwood Wilds of London (1881) 118: She [...] earns her eighteenpence a day and her ‘perks,’ which is a handy abbreviation of ‘perquisites’.
>
> 1881  [Aus]   Bulletin (Sydney) 19 Mar. 4/3: A leading undertaker writes, assuring us that he never allows any of his men to appropriate the gold tooth-plates of the defunct as perqs.
>
> 1882  [US]    Nat. Police Gaz. (NY) 23 Dec. 2/2: Detectives must have some protection and privileges [...] not to mention the ‘perks’.

Answer (score 4):

If Ngram Viewer (with smoothing disabled) is to be believed, "perk" overtook "perquisite" [around 1975 in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perquisite%2Cperk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=0), though the two had become equally common by 1943. [In BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perquisite%2Cperk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=0), "perk" overtook "perquisite" at about the same time, but the change was quite abrupt compared to that in AmE.

Comment: But that presumably is biased towards formal written English, so conversational and casual usage may have been common much earlier.

Comment: On the other hand, it may be confounded by the use of "perk" as a verb ("perk up").